# Moving forward with a proof that a non identity element exists in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The formal question is that in a group $G$, with finite elements and an element $a$, which is a non-identity element, why is it true that $|a| = 2|a^2|$?

I thought of it as a similar proof to that of $|a| = |a^{-1}|$, and tried to go from there as well as use that fact.

My proof so far:

> Attempting to prove my contradiction. 
>   Suppose $|a| = n$, where $n$ is the smallest positive integer such
>   that $|a^n = e|$, $e$ being the identity element.
>
> $$2(a^2)^n =
> > 2(a^2)^ne=2(a^2)^na^n=2(aaa...a)(aaa...a)(a^{-1}a^{-1}a^{-1}...a^{-1})_{n-times}$$
>
> $$= 2(a^n)$$
>   and we also know that $(a^{-1})^n = e$
>
> From there, we suppose that there exists a $K$ in the set of positive
>
> > integers, such that $(a^{-1})^k = e$ and $k < n$.
>
> $$a^k = a^ke$$ and so on to finish the proof.

I'm stuck from here, what is the next step I can make to progress the proof? How can I show that 2(a^2)^n is equal to $e$ so I can prove by contradiction?

Comment: This should be only true, if $|a|$ has even order. E.g. $\mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$ with $a=1$. Then $a^2=2$ and both have order 3.

Comment: You're confusing me, possibly because you are confusing yourself. $2$ is a natural number and not a member of $G$. $2|a^2|$ has nothing to do with $2a^2$.

Comment: @ctst I thought it was true, because the group is finite and then a=1 might not be in it?

Comment: @MartinKochanski Sorry Martin, yeah this question is confusing me, since it might not be a member of G, my first steps doesn't apply to this proof?

Comment: Then every element would have even order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. Take any group containing an element with odd order - the cyclic group with $5$ elements for example. Any non-identity element $a$ will have an odd order by Lagrange's Theorem and hence $|a| \neq 2|a^2|$, since this would imply $a$ to be even.

Edit: In the case the element $a$ has even order this is true. Then, if $|a^2| < \frac{|a|}{2}$ we have a contradiction  - that $|a|$ is not the order of $a$, i.e there exists $n < |a|$ such that $a^n = 1$. Clearly $(a^2)^\frac{|a|}{2} =1$ and so we deduce the result.

Second Edit: This is not necessarily true if your group has even order, consider the cyclic group with $6$ elements $C_6 = \{1,g,g^2,...,g^5\}$. Let $a = g^2$ then $|a|=|g^2|=3$ and $|a^2|=|g^4| = 3$. We need to assume $a$ has even order!

Comment: I believe you're right, I didn't reach Lagrange's application in abstract algebra but I see where you're getting at. I was trying to prove that it's right because it did say finite elements, meaning it might have the proper order, but it seems too specific now. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I've changed my answer as I noticed a mistake. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Any idea on how to disprove it without using Lagrange's theorem? Would be enough to use your second edit?

Comment: Yeah - In fact it is sufficient to use the first part of my answer. You just need to provide one counter-example to show that the claim in incorrect.